# Muscles sore and ridicously stiff after riding

Tags: mountain-bike, muscle-pain

After buying my first bike I've probably not missed a single day without sitting on the bike.

I've been probably riding 10km per day after being somewhat out of shape.

Over the days I've noticed that I lose my breath faster and faster, and my muscles seem to stiff up.

This does not hurt or feel like "postworkout"-soreness, but more like passive cramping.

That is probably the best way to describe my problem. 
I'll probably see a doc anyways but I want some more input on that

Comment: Go to a doctor. Health.Se may be better

Comment: Sounds like you're pushing too hard.  Work on endurance more than speed.   Find routes where you don't need to stop and wait for lights.  Hydrate more.  Hot shower when you get home.   Pre and Post stretching may help (no consensus on this one sadly)   And feel free to give yourself a day off to recover.... every day is ambitious to start .

Comment: Also consider using something like strava  http://strava.com/  to track your progress.   I know it generally doesn't feel faster as you progress, need something that proves your distance/speeds have improved.  Definitely helps the motivation.

Comment: Hopefully you're not riding in an area with heavy automobile exhaust or other serious air quality issues?

Comment: Define out of shape? Where is the cramping? As mentioned, rest is a good thing. Take a day (or even two) off each week when starting out.

Comment: well everything I use my upper leg muscles(i.e standing up/climbing stairs), I can feel them stiff up, similar to a mini cramp, 

but I am probably goign to see a doctor nonetheless

Comment: The symptoms you're describing could be several things, but a "metabolic disorder" (McArdles or MADD) would be high on the list.  You should see a doc (oddly a neurologist is best for these conditions), especially if you notice a rust-like sediment in your urine.  (If it's MADD there's a inexpensive supplement that will pretty much "cure" you.  McArdles, however, requires a certain amount of management to prevent permanent muscle injury.  Both conditions have significant chance of kidney injury if untreated.)

Comment: You might find eating a banana after your workout helps to limit cramping. Bananas are high in potassium, which could be depleted after a ride.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have think about your bike fit, I once had horrendous [ITB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliotibial_band_syndrome) pain from setting my seatpost just a few mm too high. There's plenty of conflicting advice and opinions you can research.

As well, are you doing any pre/post ride stretching or body care? I use a [foam roller](https://www.britishcycling.org.uk/knowledge/article/izn20140807-Physiotherapy-Foam-Roller-Routine-0) on my legs, just a few minutes in the morning and evening (I commute to work & back) does wonders.

Finally, rest days are important! If you're going every day from a history of not riding, kick back and let your body repair itself.

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles - good first answer.

Comment: Upvotes for foam rolling! Foam rolling has literally changed my life. It's really important to take good care of your muscles, and there's no substitute for foam rolling.